# 3 divs side by side when there isn't space for 3 divs, how to replace only the third one?

Tags: html, css

```css
#bio{
    width:56%;
    height:350px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#bio-text{
    width:50%;
    height:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:1%;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:#6E6E6E;
    border-radius:6px;
}

#contact{
    width:39%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:#6E6E6E;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bio">
    <div id="bio-text">
        <h2>Biography</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="bio-image"><img src="#" /></div>
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <form id="mail" method="post">
        <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0"></table>
    </form>
</div>
```

hi i have three divs one is a biography then a picture and the last one is a form.

And when i resize the browser window the picture (the middle div) is the only div moving and i want to move the last one when the browser window is resized. i have tried put the last 2 divs float right but the problem remains.

Thank you!

Comment: You have them as %, therefore they will always fit(?). Look into @media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for breakpoints in width/height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8bs39qLb/ with an example media query of max-width: 768px. If you want those three divs side by side, they should add up to a max of 100%. Float them left with a clear none and on the media query, stack them by using float none and width 100%. For a full list for various devices, see here: [css tricks media query list](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px)  {
/* Styles */
    #bio-text, #bio-image, #contact{
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a media query.

An example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) {
  #bio{
    width:50%;
  }

  #bio-text{
    width:50%;
  }

  #contact{
    width:100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap framework.. use bootstrap classes for managing the column layout i.e col-md-3(medium devices),col-sm-3(small devices) which will automatically adjust as per the device aspect ratio.